Getting a ValueError on loading a custom keras model
I have made a Custom Keras model for Machine Translation. After saving the model as tf_model.keras , during loading I am getting an error. I have added get_config() and from_config() function and also added @keras.saving.register_keras_serializable() at the top of the class.
Note : I have saved and loaded the model in colab file where the model has been trained and it successfully loaded the model there but while loading it in other environment it is giving ValueError
Model:
@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class BidirectionalEncoderandDecoderWithAttention(keras.Model):
    def __init__(
            self,
            **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder_embedding = Embedding(14617, 256, mask_zero=True)
        self.encoder = Bidirectional(LSTM(512 // 2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True))
        self.decoder_embedding = Embedding(29604, 256, mask_zero=True)
        self.decoder = LSTM(512, return_sequences=True)
        self.attention = Attention()
        self.output_layer = Dense(29604, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, inputs):
        encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs = inputs
        encoder_embeddings = self.encoder_embedding(encoder_inputs)
        decoder_embeddings = self.decoder_embedding(decoder_inputs)

        encoder_op, *encoder_state = self.encoder(encoder_embeddings)
        encoder_state = [
            tf.concat(encoder_state[0::2], axis=-1),
            tf.concat(encoder_state[1::2], axis=-1),
        ]
        decoder_op = self.decoder(decoder_embeddings, initial_state=encoder_state)
        attention_output = self.attention([decoder_op, encoder_op])
        output = self.output_layer(attention_output)
        return output

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        return config

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)

Summary of the model
I am loading the model as my_model = keras.models.load_model("tf_model.keras", custom_objects={ 'BidirectionalEncoderandDecoderWithAttention': BidirectionalEncoderandDecoderWithAttention}) and also defined the BidirectionalEncoderandDecoderWithAttention class in the same file but getting following error:
ValueError: Layer 'embedding' expected 1 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['embedding/embeddings:0']


Here are a few things you can check:

Ensure consistent environments:
The model loads successfully in the Colab environment where it was trained, but fails in a different environment. This suggests there might be version inconsistencies between the environments. Make sure you're using the same versions of TensorFlow, Keras, and other relevant libraries in both environments.

Properly register custom objects:
The error message indicates that the model is expecting variables for the embedding layer but receiving none. This could be because the custom layer class is not properly registered or recognized when loading. Ensure that the BidirectionalEncoderandDecoderWithAttention class is defined exactly the same way in the loading environment as it was during training.

Use tf.keras consistently:
If you used tf.keras to create and save the model, make sure you're also using tf.keras to load it, not the standalone Keras library

Save and load in HDF5 format:
If the issue persists, try saving your model in the HDF5 format (.h5 extension) instead of the newer .keras format. This older format might be more compatible across different environments


I also found a post discussing similar error on GitHub keras repo. Have a look:
got ValueError when loading model that have LSTM Layer.
